# How effective is sinovac/sinopharm vaccine

Tags: covid-19, medications, side-effects, coronavirus

it's time for me to get vaccinated with sinovac vaccine. I am actually a little bit nervous, about its effectiveness, I am not a docotor and I have no idea what's behind it. I am worrying that it might damage my body, like my brain (it might be a stupid idea). what do you think? is this vaccine safe?

Answer (score 1):

You may not have had a chance to see this from the WHO: https://www.who.int/news-room/feature-stories/detail/the-sinovac-covid-19-vaccine-what-you-need-to-know

> "The WHO Strategic Advisory Group of Experts (SAGE) on Immunization
> has issued Interim recommendations for the use of the inactivated
> COVID-19 vaccine, Sinovac-CoronaVac, developed by Sinovac/China
> National Pharmaceutical Group.

...

> Is it safe?
>
> SAGE has thoroughly assessed the data on quality, safety and efficacy
> of the vaccine and has recommended its use for people aged 18 and
> above.
>
> Safety data is currently limited for persons above 60 years of age
> (due to the small number of participants in clinical trials).
>
> While no differences in safety profile of the vaccine in older adults
> compared to younger age groups can be anticipated, countries
> considering using this vaccine in persons older than 60 years should
> maintain active safety monitoring.
>
> As part of the EUL process, Sinovac has committed to continuing submit
> data on safety, efficacy and quality in ongoing vaccine trials and
> rollout in populations, including in older adults.
>
> How efficacious is the vaccine?
>
> A large phase 3 trial in Brazil showed that two doses, administered at
> an interval of 14 days, had an efficacy of 51% against symptomatic
> SARS-CoV-2 infection, 100% against severe COVID-19, and 100% against
> hospitalization starting 14 days after receiving the second dose. Does
> it work against new variants of SARS-CoV-2 virus?
>
> In an observational study, the estimated effectiveness of
> Sinovac-CoronaVac in health workers in Manaus, Brazil, where P.1
> accounted for 75% of SARS-CoV-2 samples was 49.6% against symptomatic
> infection (4). Effectiveness has also been shown in an observational
> study in Sao Paulo in the presence of P1 circulation (83% of samples).
>
> Assessments in settings where the P.2 Variant of Concern was widely
> circulating – also in Brazil - estimated vaccine effectiveness of
> 49.6% following at least one dose and demonstrated 50.7% two weeks after the second dose. As new data becomes available, WHO will update
> recommendations accordingly.
>
> SAGE currently recommends using this vaccine, according to the WHO
> Prioritization Roadmap."

Also note that this vaccine is a killed-virus type of vaccine, different from the adenovirus-vector types of vaccines that have been in the news recently due to possible very very rare blood clot issues.

More detailed resources:

"Interim recommendations for use of the inactivated COVID-19 vaccine, CoronaVac, developed by Sinovac"
https://www.who.int/publications/i/item/WHO-2019-nCoV-vaccines-SAGE-recommendation-Sinovac-Coronavac

"Annexes to the recommendations for use of the Sinovac-CoronaVac vaccine against COVID-19: Grading of evidence, Evidence to recommendation tables"
https://www.who.int/publications/i/item/WHO-2019-nCoV-vaccines-SAGE_recommendation-Sinovac-CoronaVac-annexes-2021.1

"Background document on the inactivated vaccine Sinovac-CoronaVac against COVID-19"
https://www.who.int/publications/i/item/WHO-2019-nCoV-vaccines-SAGE-recommendation-Sinovac-CoronaVac-background

Comment: 51% is too less, so i guess it's not effective and might cause some bad side effects in long run, that's what this 51% tells me

Comment: There is nothing about "some bad side effects" in the above. The 51% says that vaccinated people were roughly half as likely as unvaccinated people to develop any Covid symptoms, and the 100% means vaccinated people were 100% protected against having to be hospitalized from Covid and 100% protected against getting a severe case of Covid. That is the opposite of "not effective".